# Conditional ng-repeat ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ui router ($routeprovider and $locationprovider)for angular js. I want to change the array of which to loop through in a ng-repeat depending on the current url/route. I have read similar posts here on stack but can't find an exact solution to my problem.

These are my routes

```
   .when('/limited', {
          template: '<di-home></di-home>',
          activeTab: 'home',
          caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
      })

   .when('/all', {
          template: '<di-home></di-home>',
          activeTab: 'home',
          caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
      })
```

when the url changes i want to change the ng-repeat from "things in Ctrl.data.all" to "things in Ctrl.data.limited" with some kind of an if-statement.

```
<md-card class="md-whiteframe-4dp" ng-repeat="things in Ctrl.data.all" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="100" flex-md="45" flex-gt-md="30"></md-card>
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? Can you point me in the right direction/ to a similar post? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that in your view, it is a job for your controller. Keep the view simple:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="things in dataToDisplay"></md-card>
```

Then in controller, depending of your URL, set `$scope.data`:

```
if($location.path() === '/limited') {
    $scope.dataToDisplay = $scope.data.limited;
} else if($location.path() === '/all') {
    $scope.dataToDisplay = $scope.data.all;
}
```

*PS: Don't forget to inject `$location` in your controller.*

Comment: Do i need to inject $location?

Comment: @andrea Yes, inject it into your controller

Comment: I don't get it to work. My html now looks exactly like your example and my js looks like this: Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'update', '$document', '$location']; 

    /* @ngInject */
    function Controller($scope, update, $document, $location) {
        var NewsCtrl = this;

        if ($location.path() === '/home') {
            NewsCtrl.dataToDisplay = NewsCtrl.data.all;
        } else if ($location.path() === '/limited') {
            NewsCtrl.dataToDisplay = NewsCtrl.data.limited;
        }